# Calculate constant power applied to accelerate a mass over a given distance and time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, power

I'm trying to determine electric motor power sizing with requirements given for covering a particular distance within a certain time. The knowns are the vehicle mass, the allotted time, the target distance to cover, and the vehicles initial velocity. The result would be used as the absolute minimum possible motor output power rating that would satisfy the requirement.

Comment: well, you are increasing the kinetic energy of the vehicle using some power over a given time. So equate energy in to energy out.